# Unix on the H11?

Tags: unix

I'm curious if anyone is aware of actual uses of Unix on the [Heathkit H11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathkit_H11)? I don't see any technical reason a memory-expanded H11 couldn't run Unix, but can't find any examples of it doing so.

Comment: Plausible. The H11 is an LSI-11/02 with max 32 kW of memory, and Unix "V6 will run on an LSI-11/02 with 28KW of memory." https://www.mail-archive.com/cctalk@classiccmp.org/msg44100.html

Comment: Nice question. Can't provide an Answer. Still, AFAICT, it should work. The H11 was basically a PDP 11/40, while the H11A is the equivalent of a 11/02, and could use any Q-Bus interface, including disks. Heath themself supplied an RX01 alike floppy and a RT11 version. So loading (some) Unix might work quite well - given a disk controller (Q-Bus SCSI or alike) is added.

Comment: Did these CPUs lack supervisor mode? and if so, did Unix need it?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz AFAIK they were exactly the same as in the corresponding PDPs. Maybe Stephen knows more about what is required.

Comment: An LSI-11 has an 11/40-ish instruction set but it doesn't have an MMU, so it's a single-mode single-space processor. That limits the operating systems you might run.  From dusty memory cells, also, the PS is not accessible through the IO page (like normal -11 CPUs), but only via a new instruction, so it's likely not even binary compatible with unmapped operating systems.

Comment: @ralfzahn - careful with that "11/02".  Generally speaking, "11/xx" means "PDP-11/xx", and there's no such thing as a PDP-11/02.  There's also an "LSI-11", which is the microprocessor and/or the CPU module used in the PDP-11/03, and an LSI-11/2, no zero, which is its replacement (same microprocessor, different CPU module).  Ain't DEC nomenclature grand?  As far as I can tell from the 'net, the H11 was based on the LSI-11 board, and the H11A was based on the LSI-11/2 board. They're both 16-bit bus devices.

Comment: In the early (V6 days) there were a couple of mini versions of V6 that ran on an MMUless 28Kw system. Hans Lycklama's mini-unx could run on the minimal 11s but you'd still have needed a disk subsystem that didn't suck. I suspect that is actually the bigger issue - a 256K floppy does not cut it.